# Supporting multiple languages for model metadata

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.Net and particularly ASP.Net Core, is there any way to implement multi-language meta-data for models? For instance, given the following:

```
public class _Person{
   [Required]
   [Display(Name = "First Name")] // If English
   [Display(Name = "Prenom")] // If French 
   public String FirstName {get; set}
}
```

and providing error message according to the language if no value is provided for that property in a form, or the max string length exceeds the allowed size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create multiple .resx files for each language you want to support. You can then link the resx file via:

```
[Display(Name = "FirstName", ResourceType = typeof(NameOfRescourceFile))]
```

[The resource file would look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Il8l.png)

If you want to know how to create these .resx files take a look at this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247246.aspx)